# Reset the mainpanel screen once another file is uploaded in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to design a shiny app that the file name will display on the main panel once the file is uploaded and the submit button is pressed. The code below works to some extent, but the issue is that after the first file is uploaded, the name of subsequent file will display automatically once it is uploaded. I want to ask how I can modify the code so that once the next file is uploaded, the name of the previous file will disappear, and the name of the currently uploaded file will appear only after I click the submit button.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Choose File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("csv")
                ),
      actionButton("action", "Submit")
    ),
      mainPanel(textOutput("text"))
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    output$text = renderText(input$file$name)
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression within the `observeEvent()` references `input$file` and therefore creates a reactive relationship to `input$file`. This triggers an update as soon as `input$file` changes. You can use `isolate()` to prevent the reactive relationship.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(
      "file",
      "Choose File",
      multiple = FALSE,
      accept = c("csv")
    ),
    actionButton("action", "Submit")
  ),
  mainPanel(textOutput("text"))
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    output$text = renderText(isolate(input$file$name))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    output$text = renderText("")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your suggestion works to prevent input$file react immediately before pressing the submit button. However, is there a way to have the previous file name to disappear right after I upload a new file and before clicking the submit button?

Comment: you could add a second `observeEvent()` for `input$file`, which sets the text output to "". I edited my answer to include that idea.

Comment: It works. Thanks